# Can I replace .git folder for fixing broken reporistory?

Tags: git, .git-folder

One week ago, my local reporistory has been broken somehow due to some corrupted files. And while trying to fix my repository I have deleted broken files and tried lots of other things that I am not very familiar.

During this period I have also worked on my project without committing.

Can I fix my local repository with replacing `.git` folder with the folder that is downloaded from remote.

Note that I don't want to lose works of last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When just some files are broken:

What you can do is get the current status of your repo via

```
git status
```

in a console to check which parts of your git repository are broken / has changed. Now you can just checkout the original version via

```
git checkout <filename>
```

When something else like the branch is broken: check via

```
git branch
```

the current branch. You can checkout the correct version via

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

If you have some other issues: Of course you can checkout the remote repo and copy the files manually into your local copy.
But never touch the .git-folders if you do not know what are the meaning of the data stored there. Try to fix your repo with the git-tools makes more sense.